# Shared TTS no working after Activity is dead then alive again

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I took the code below and it works fine, sharing the TTS object to other activities:

```
       package com.simekadam.blindguardian;

            import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

public class SpeechHelper implements OnInitListener {

private static TextToSpeech mTts;
private String text; 
private static final SpeechHelper helper = new SpeechHelper();

public static SpeechHelper getInstance(){

    return helper;
}


public void say(String text, Context context){

    if(mTts == null){
        this.text = text;
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(context, (OnInitListener) helper);

    }
    else{
        mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}


@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}

public void stopTTS(){
    if(mTts != null){
        mTts.shutdown();
        mTts.stop();
        mTts = null;
    }
}

}
```

However, if I leave the activity and then I come back to it, my app simply doesn't speak anymore. No errors. It just doesn't speak anymore.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

I just saw the following message in my messages in Eclipse: *"sending message to a handler on a dead thread"*

What could I make to solve this? =)

Comment: The code is written in `onCreate` of Activity

    Intent checkIntent ... PUT that into onResume() of that activity.

Comment: Hello Soni, thank you for your answer. What code you say I should put into onResume()? The link above has a lot of code! =^) I edited it to include EXACTLY the code that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

This error does not show up if you use the application context instead of the current activity. For example:

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(context.getApplicationContext(), (OnInitListener) helper);
```

Comment: Most of the answers talk about implementing the TTSHelper as a service and other complicated architecture, when indeed switching to the application context does make sense and it works. Thanks @aleb